# Angular module decorator is missing from declaration file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to generate the declaration files for an Angular application. I have a module named `CoreModule` that looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA
  ],
  imports: [
    ModuleA
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceA
  ],
  exports: [
    ComponentA
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

I have a `tsconfig.types.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outFile": "index.d.ts",
    ...
  }
}
```

And when I do `tsc --project tsconfig.types.json` I get something like

```
declare module "core/src/app/core.module" {
    export class CoreModule {
        constructor();
    }
}
```

Which is missing all the information that was included in the NgModule decorator like declarations, imports, providers and exports.

If I create an Angular library with the same code and I run `ng build core` (which uses ng-packagr instead of webpack) I correctly get something like

```
export declare class CoreModule {
    constructor();
    static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<CoreModule, never>;
    static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<CoreModule, [typeof i1.ComponentA, ...]>;
    static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<CoreModule>;
}
```

Can you explain why I'm missing all the extra properties in the first case and what should I do to include them?